# Computer does not boot with single RAM stick

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, bios

My computer has 2x2GB RAM right now and this works fine. I got one stick (from another computer) that is 8GB and I want to put it into my computer. All memory is DDR3.

However, the computer does not boot at all if I have a single stick in any of the channels - it just sits there with a black screen and doesn't even go to BIOS, so I have no idea what it's upset about.

I have tried:

- Putting 8GB into slot 1 (out of 1-4), no other RAM. Same problem. I've tried it alone in all four slots.
- Putting 2x2GB into slots 1+3, 8GB into slot 2, same problem
- Putting 8GB into slot 1, 2x2GB into 2+4, same problem
- Putting 1x2GB into slot 1, no other RAM. Same issue.
- Increasing the DRAM voltage slightly (to 1.51), same problem.
- Changed the DRAM timing to match the new stick, same problem.

So I don't think it has to do with the RAM stick itself, but rather the motherboard or the processor I guess. I was under the impression that all motherboards would support a single RAM stick regardless, but apparently that isn't the case?

My hardware:

- CPU: AMD FX-8320E
- Motherboard: MSI 970
- RAM 2x2GB: Corsair CMX4GX3M2A1600C9
- RAM 8GB: Corsair CMV8GX3M1A1600C11

My BIOS is up to date (M40). What could be going on?

**Edit:** I think it's the RAM stick. I got my computer to boot with 1 or 2 of the 2GB sticks that I currently use after resetting the BIOS. But I cannot get this new one to do anything. Oh well, guess it's back to the store tomorrow!

Comment: While it might be the RAM stick itself, are you familiar with [dual channel memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-channel_architecture)? Some motherboards won't boot if the memory isn't configured to be in dual channel (i.e. same RAM types/speed/size in the conjoining slots) .. and that motherboard is a dual-channel board (at least from the specs I could find) ..

Comment: @txtechhelp, it turns out it can boot fine (as per my edit) with a single stick of old ram. So I don't think it's the motherboard being "dual-channel". I am familiar with dual channel memory though.

Comment: Could be a tiny short or blown IC on the stick that causes the system to not respond (e.g. no boot because the RAM doesn't "complete the circuit" so-to-speak) .. It's always a bummer when a module goes out :/

Comment: @txtechhelp, yeah, I got the RAM stick replaced (yesterday) and the new one worked right away. I think it was just a faulty stick. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

MSI 970 supports maximum 32 GB ( 4 x 8 GB) DDR3 1066/1333/1600/1866

Since the 8 GB module is not recognizing by the Motherboard, the memory could be at fault.

Refer specifications here:
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/970-GAMING.html#hero-specification